# Way to explain all mysql select queries "Kohana Framework 3" model

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, query-builder

Using **Kohana framework *v3*** I have created model with `N` methods using query builder. For example `N-10%` - use `DB::select()`.
 Is there any integrated functionality to do `explain select` for each method which use `DB::select()`?

I think to do this in this way:

Extend base query builder class and in Application folder remap  `execute()` function with same code as was original, but add string which will write into `mysql_log_of_selects.txt` result of execution each select query with prepended `EXPLAIN` to it.
But what will propose you? Thanks!

Comment: I don really understand what is your goal. You need the last executed query string?

Comment: @mobal, I need to do something like "stress test for mysql queries".
So I want to add "`EXPLAIN `" Before each final query and result of execution save to log file. My question is: Does the KO3 have this functionality, or I must extend base DB class and modify it?

Comment: Extend the base class or your model with this logic. I think there is no options (i searched but not found) like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend base query builder class and in Application folder remap  execute() function with same code as was in original, but add "EXPLAIN " before each final query and result of it's execution save to log file.